# Smoke Screen vs Reflects Damage

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that Smoke Screen is supposed to be an invulnerability skill that protects you from enemy damage. But can it protect you from your own damage? ie. Can it protect you from damage reflected from your own attacks due to enemy thorns from Reflects Damage affix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  While you are under the effects of smoke screen you will not take any RD damage.